# Keep page scroll position of a page in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm using Svelte, and trying to keep the scroll position on a single page such when a user navigates to another page and then navigates back (through back in the browser or the navbar) the page loads and keeps same scroll position.

I've tried doing this using a store, and the `<svelte:window>` element. According to the note [here](https://svelte.dev/docs/special-elements#svelte-window) I should use `onMount` to scroll the page on mount. This is what I've tried:

```js
// scrollPosition.ts
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

export const y = writable(0)

// component.svelte
<script lang="ts">
import { y } from '$lib/stores'
import { onMount } from 'svelte'

onMount(() => {
  scrollTo(0, $y)
})
</script>

<svelte:window bind:scrollY={$y} />
...
```

I've verified the store is updated with scroll position, and when the component mounts it is being reset to 0. So no scroll actually happens on mount.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving the problem differently; instead of binding the scroll to the store using `<svelte:window>` I saved the scroll position `onDestroy` and reused it `onMount`.

```
onDestroy(() => ($y = window.scrollY))
onMount(async () => {
    await tick()
    scrollTo(0, $y)
})
```

Comment: You don't use SvelteKit? You get this functionality for free if you do.

Comment: No, my backend is implemented using diff language